# QDialog-derived form closes immediately

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a form with data table appear when the button is clicked on thr main form. However, in practice second form 'blinks' - appears less than on second - and then vanished. What could be the reason and how that should be fixed?

Here is the derived form header and source files' content:

```
#ifndef GOODTABLE_H
#define GOODTABLE_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QSqlTableModel>
namespace Ui {
    class GoodTable;
}

class GoodTable : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit GoodTable(QDialog *parent = 0);
    GoodTable(QDialog *parent,QSqlTableModel* model);
    ~GoodTable();

private:
    Ui::GoodTable *ui;
};

#endif // GOODTABLE_H

#include "goodtable.h"
#include "ui_goodtable.h"

GoodTable::GoodTable(QDialog *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::GoodTable)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
GoodTable::GoodTable(QDialog *parent,QSqlTableModel* model) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::GoodTable)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}
GoodTable::~GoodTable()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The code creating second window:

```
void MainWindow::on_goodTable_clicked()
{
    QSqlTableModel model;

    initializeGoodModel(&model);
    //! [4]
    GoodTable view(NULL,&model);
    view.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
    view.setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
    view.show();
}
```

Comment: Quite unrelated comment: Why do you make the `ui` member variable (encapsulating the designer created form) dynamic (new/delete). This is not Java. Just make it a simple member variable (not a pointer) or better, privately derive your `GoodTable` from it (in addition to the public inheritance from `QDialog`).

Comment: just using what QT Creator embedded designer gave me; will look into remaking that part.

Comment: @Christian Rau: This is a fairly common method of handling the UI, in that it means the class header file doesn't include the generated UI file, so 1) UI changes don't cause other, unrelated files to recompile, and 2) it clearly shows that other classes have no need to know what is in the UI.

Comment: @Caleb I understand your arguments. Haven thought it from that side, I have to admit. Although I have never been a friend of the pimpl idiom.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is, that you have a local dialog object on the stack in your `on_goodTable_clicked` method. So you create the `view`, call `show`, which shows the dialog and immediately returns, then your `view` get's destroyed as you leave the function. If you make the dialog modal anyway, why not use `QDialog`'s `exec` method intead of `show`. It shows the dialog and blocks the main window until you clicked the dialog's Ok or cancel button and then `exec` finally returns. When you want a non-modal dialog (meaning your main window works, while the dialog is open), you need to create your dialog dynamically (or make it a member of your main window, or both).

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem - and my problem with non-displaying QTableView as well (another question of mine).

Comment: if that's not too hard for you: could you tell, whether rows can be deleted or added with basic QTableView?

Comment: The table view is a model/view class (read about model/view in the Qt doc). So you have to remove the row from the underlying model. But as this is an SQL model, you probably need to use some database functionality for that (I'm sure QSqlQuery or a similar class has a method for removing a row), but perhaps the QSqlTableModel just implements a removeRow function from the base model, that removes a row from the database table.

Comment: I am more concerned with figuring out the right row to delete and when to do it. As far as i can gather, i need to handle a press of "Del" when the entire row is chosen. But how to do THAT i have little to no idea.

Comment: Juts look at the `QSqlTableModel` or it's base classes. I think the currently selected row can be queried quite easily from the `QTableView` or the model. Take a closer look at Qt's documentation (which is really detailed and helpful), especially the section about the model/view architecture. It also has many example applications.

Comment: You are right again. After some search i found how to get current row selection from QTableView, and that solved my problem.